# How do I find $g(x)$ from $f(g(x))$ and $f '(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, function-and-relation-composition

Given $f(g(x)) = x$, and $f '(x) = 1 + [f(x)]^2$, how do I find $g '(x)$?

I have tried, subbing $g(x)$ into $f'(x)$ and got that $f'(g(x)) = 1+x^2$ but I am not sure if I am doing the right thing. It seems like a very simple problem but I'm having trouble with it.

Comment: Perhaps you can follow this kind of logic:
$$
f(g(x)) = x \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad g(x) = f^{-1}(x)
$$
what is $g'(x)$ now ? What is the derivative of an inverse function?

Answer (score 4):

Since
$$
\frac{df}{dx} = 1 + f^2
$$
we have
$$
\int \frac{df}{1+f^2} = \int dx
$$
Then
$$
\arctan{f} = x + C \iff f = \tan \left( x + C \right)
$$

From which we immediately get
$$
g(x)=\arctan x-C
$$
Thus
$$
g'(x) =\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$[f(g(x))]'=f'(g(x))g'(x)=[x]'=1$$
By assumption $f'(g(x))=1+[f(g(x))]^2=1+x^2$ and hence
$$f'(g(x))g'(x)=(1+x^2)g'(x)=1\implies g'(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$$